# Changing SQL query into an eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to turn this SQL query into an eloquent query but my experience and knowledge in eloquent is a bit lacking. I would love to learn how to fix this problem myself, but all of the solutions I have tried have failed and I'm having an issue on the production environment.

Basically I have an inbox system, and I group all of the messages in the database to the sender id. I want it to group it by the send ID, and display the latest message from the sender.

I've managed to get it work with just raw SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE id IN(
    SELECT MAX(id)
        FROM `messages`
        WHERE `recieveid` = 1
        GROUP BY `sendid`
) ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
```

However I'm unsure how to turn it into an eloquent statement using the models. I'm currently using something simple like this, but it does not order them by time, so it can miss a few messages out.

```
$getMessages = \App\Message::where("recieveid", Auth::user()->id)- 
>orderBy("id","desc")->groupBy("sendid")->get(10);
```

Comment: One thing that might help you is to dd() the results with ->toSql() instead of ->get() https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel#toc-simple-query-debugging

Comment: Another suggestion is once you have the collection $getMessages, you can order/sort that by date.  However, wouldn't ordering it by the ID accomplish the same thing, since the most recent ID would be the most recent created entry?

Comment: What's the use of the `GROUP BY` in your inner query here? I think you could drop that. And I don't think the inner query is valid SQL in strict mode at the moment

Comment: It groups it by the sender. It basically lists each sender and displays the latest message that they sent. If I remove that, then only one single row is returned (the latest message). Even if it isn't valid, it's working perfect for me when I run the query directly on the database. I just need something that has the same result as it using eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you!

```
// SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE id IN ...
$sql = Message::whereIn('id', function ($query) {
    // SELECT MAX(id)
    return $query->select(DB::raw('max(id)'))
        // FROM `messages`
        ->from(with(new Message)->getTable())
        // WHERE `recieveid` = 1
        ->where('recieveid', 1)
        // GROUP BY `sendid`
        ->groupBy('sendid');
})
// ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
```